# razor websites not working and all dlls are present

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, templates, razor

I've uploaded a `.cshtml` website to a `surftown` server, and I got some problems running the code. But I have a problem with it running the `Razor` code.

This is how the page renders:(Default.cshtml) [image]

I've already checked for internal communication problems. And this is my result:
[image]

But then why isn't it working, and how can I fix it?

I've heard that it can be a problem with views but how whould I fix this if that's the case?

My websites folder tree: (And some files too)

- App_Code
- App_Data

  - packages

    - Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.2.0.20710.0
    - Microsoft.Asp.Net.WebPages.2.0.20710.0
    - Microsoft.Asp.Net.WebPages.Administration.2.0.20710.0
    - Microsoft.Asp.Net.WebPages.Data.2.0.20710.0
    - Microsoft.Asp.Net.WebPages.WebData.2.0.20710.0
    - Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0
    - NuGet.Core.1.6.2
- bin
- packages

  - jQuery.2.0.3

    - Content

      - Scripts
    - Tools
  - Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.30506.0

    - lib

      - net40
  - Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.2.0.30506.0

    - lib

      - net40

  - Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0

    - lib

      - net40
- Pages

  - Chapters

    - Read.cshtml
  - Edit

    - Move

      - Chapter.cshtml
    - Entry.cshtml
  - Entries

    - EnterEntry.cshtml
    - EnterNote.cshtml
  - Login

    - Login.cshtml
  - Search

    - Result.cshtml
- Scripts

  - Addons

    - TinyMCE
- Styles

  - CSS
- Views

  - _Layout.cshtml
- Default.cshtml

My web.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
              <buildProviders>
                <add extension=".cshtml" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider, System.Web.WebPages.Razor"/>
              </buildProviders>
              <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
              </assemblies>
            </compilation>
          </system.web>
          <connectionStrings>
            <add connectionString="database connection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
          </connectionStrings>
        </configuration>
```

EDIT:
Is it a problem that all my files are `.cshtml`? And that they are added as `MIME Type` `html/text`.

More Edit:
This is my Default.cshtml code:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h1 class="header">
                            Welcome to the library
                        </h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>
                            Do look around, to find information about almost anything there is to know about Mythodea, or maybe you are here to make a chapter or note of your own.
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And my _Layout.cshtml code:
    @{
        // A bunch of C# code
    }

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link href="~/Styles/CSS/Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="~/Scripts/Addons/TinyMCE/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @RenderSection("head",false)

    <title>The Kettle Library of Mythodea</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>
                The Library
            </h1>
        </div>

        <div id="left_column">
            <div class="innerPadding">
                <div id="Menu_Overview">
                    @Html.Raw(menu)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="right_column">
            <div class="innerPadding">
                @{
                    if(!SessionHandler.UserIsLoggedIn)
                    {
                        <div class="Login_Wrapper">
                            <form action="" method="post">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <p>
                                                Username/Email:
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input class="form_input" type="text" placeholder="Username / Email" tabindex="1" name="username" value="@username" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <p>
                                                Password:
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input class="form_input" type="password" placeholder="Password" tabindex="2" name="password" />
                                            <a href="#">forgot?</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="submit" value="Login" name="btn" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="submit" value="Register" name="btn" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </form>
                            <p class="Error_Message">@message_error</p>
                        </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="Login_Wrapper">
                            <form action="" method="post">
                                <p>
                                    @name
                                </p>
                                <input type="submit" value="Logout" name="btn" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    }
                }

                <div class="SideMenu_Right">
                    <div id="search_wrapper">
                        <form action="" method="post">
                            <input type="text" name="searchField" placeholder="Search" value="@searchValue" required="required" />
                            <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Search" />
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    @{
                        if(SessionHandler.UserIsLoggedIn)
                        {
                            <a href="~/Pages/Entries/EnterEntry.cshtml">Create new Chapter</a>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        }
                    }

                    @RenderSection("menu_right", false)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="middle_column">
            <div class="innerPadding">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="madeBy">
        <p>
            Created by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/michaeltot.korsgaard" target="_blank">Michael Tot Korsgaard</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to put the error/issue in the question, not an external link. How would the next guy solve his problem looking at this if your page is now working/no longer exists?

Comment: Changed the links to images. Thanks for the heads-up ^^

Comment: Great. My first guess is that your IIS is not configured properly. Is it set to the correct Asp.net version for instance? Edit - Ok I see it in the screen shot, that does look right....

Comment: The correct folder structure here should be `~/views/_viewstart.cshtml` with the Layout line, then a corresponding layout file in `~/views` that renders the body. I always have mine in `~/views/shared/` not in just `~/views`, can you check and make sure that it's setup that way and all the paths are correct?

Comment: Now the `Default.cshtml` is calling the `_Layout.cshtml` which is found in `~/Views/_Layout.cshtml`. But same problem.

Comment: Views don't call the layout, it's exactly opposite - the layout renders the view.

Comment: Can you explain more why this won't work, since the website works fine whe n I test it, but not when I upload it to the server?

Comment: which version of mvc are you using (3 or 4)? Have you created deployable dependancies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It seems that you are not using MVC architecture. Why you are using `Pages` rather than `Views`?**
I have seen all of your errors and every thing works properly. Solving deployment problems in this manner is too hard. So I put basic instructions for deploying MVC applications on real server maybe useful:

1. Make sure your application will run properly on localhost and you
   have not changed normal application routine or did not any unwanted
   mistake on default application configuration.
2. Then add required assembly references to your project due to
   compile/run additional MVC extensions like razor by following this:
   right-Click on your project -> Add deployable dependencies -> mark
   both MVC & Razor -> OK
3. Then right-click on your project again -> build deployment package |
   then it will ready for publish.
4. Then normally try publishing process

Till now you have configured application for working with windows server and although it wouldn't support MVC technology, your application have related assembly references to run/compile on server. Now all things are related to Server and IIS configuration. follow the following instructions:

1. configure IIS by [THIS](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-manager).(if your host supports this type of
   connection)
2. If the server is yours, make sure you have no anomalies in
   application configuration and root server configurations related to
   .net Framework.

**Edit:**

About default page rendering in MVC consider that in **Global.asax** file we set default route like bellow (by caling `RegisterRoutes` function of `RouteConfig` class) :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

In MVC Architecture we don't work with traditional ASP page routing like using **Default.cshtml**.
Each Controller Calls his same name folder in Views Folder and controls .cshtml subpages according to its action methods. No choice available to rename Default View folder placed on application.
About Mastering pages consider that by default each MVC application when decided to render view, first calls **_ViewStart.cshtml** file placed at **root of View folder** to understand what's the name of master page according to _ViewStart content. At this Step to next we have master and partial views concepts.

For Example if you try to change the name of _ViewStart.cshtml file (for example _Start.cshtml) you will see the following page at browser :

[image: Error When changing _ViewStart.cshtml file name]

**So In working with MVC Architecture, you must follow some rules/contracts to build successful applications.**

Comment: I understand that it whould make more sense having `Views` instead of `Pages` but what I don't understand is why that whould make a problem when `Default.cshtml` (which is at the website root, and not in `Views`) is calling the views `_Layout.cshtml` who are placed in `Views`?

PS: Is trying to check whether my server host supports the IIS connection

Comment: My server is using IIS 7

Comment: No Problem with IIS 7. You need .net 4 support. I Place Call hierarchy of Views in my answer too perhaps will be your comment answer.

Comment: The server supports .net 4

Comment: So what you have added to support `Pages` Directory?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the web.config from your Views / Pages folder

It should be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I've added your code to my `web.config` and now I get a 404 error with every single page I load. Did I miss something?

Comment: This would be why:
`<httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>` Perhaps try creating new MVC project and copy the generated web.config